# What are the benefits of having a space advantage in a closed position?

Tags: strategy, pawns, closed-position, space

I notice that in my closed games when I find myself with an advantage in space, I have more mobility for my pieces and thats all good but once I reach this position I'm never really able to find a plan and never know how to make use of this advantage. Does anybody know how I can make use of it whether that be by opening up a file or trying to create a passed pawn? I never really know how to identify these ideas and generally look for a tactical line or idea that never comes up.

Comment: Could you please link such a game for me? I cannot figure out the exact problems in the position and also if you can link a game maybe answers could also point to how the theory is used in practice

Answer (score 5):

Michael Stean, in his "Simple chess" introduced the idea of the "capacity" of a given Pawn structure. How many pieces can live inside it without getting in each others way. If your opponents pawns do not have enough capacity for his pieces, he will have difficulty manoeuvering them to defend. This introduces the "principle of two weaknesses" You inflict two weaknesses in your opponents structure. You can switch your attack from one to the other faster than they can switch their defence. The nature of the weaknesses can be whatever is in the position. A vulnerable King, a weak Pawn, a desirable exchange, establishing control of a file...It can be an end in itself or a stepping stone to something else. Search for "two weaknesses" on Youtube.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a material advantage, do not play as if it in itself guarantees a win.  Act aggressively and seek an active plan.  This principle is often violated especially by less aggressive chess players, who often stop active play, having achieved a material advantage, believing that it will automatically lead to victory.  This is not the case, and as a rule, the opponent seizes the initiative.
Striving for risk-free play in a winning position allows the opponent to extend resistance and sometimes gives him a chance to escape.
The main thing is to keep the initiative.  Steinitz's rule: "the one with the advantage must attack under the threat of losing this advantage." You should also analyze the position that interests you (analyze the game).  after the game, of course, establish and analyze the moves using a computer in order to understand where you make mistakes and miscalculations.  Deconstruct Nimzowitsch's games!

Steinitz's main thesis is: "set yourself a plan that would be in accordance with the situation."

1. If there are no flaws in the opponent's position, then you need to create a weakness in his camp;
2. The object of attack in the endgame
   are pawns, and therefore
   you need to try to form a weak
   fight in a pawn structure rival.
3. The key to the opponent's position may be the capture of the field.
   Practice creating weaknesses in your opponent's position.  Remember that it is important to find the most vulnerable spot in his defense. Targeting the weakest point in the enemy position.
   Note further that, although the combination recedes into the background in Steinitz's teachings, it is still for
   achieving consistent good results is very important.  for with its help the advantageous position turns into a win.  There is a well-known dictum: “the most difficult thing is to win a won position” - it shows that most often chess players lack the ability to combine accurately and sharply.  To achieve this, it is necessary to study deeply the game of Andersen and Morphy before turning to the Steinitz method.